# how to inject an iframe panel to a Google Chrome extension and add click event inside the iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I did an extension that inject iframe to the current webpage, using Content-scripts:

```
$('body').append('<iframe src="' + chrome.extension.getURL('panel.html') + '" frameborder="0" style="border-top-width: 0px; border-right-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; border-left-width: 0px; border-style: initial; border-color: initial; z-index: 2147483647; position: fixed; width: 100%; left: 0px; bottom: 0px; height: 100px; display: block; visibility: visible; outline-style: none; outline-width: 0px; outline-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); " id="GE_Panel"></iframe>');
```

I can view the iframe in the webpage, but I don't know how to add click event for an element, that inside the iframe...

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait until the iframe has loaded and then access the elements inside of it:

E.g.

```
$('<iframe ... />').load(function() {
    var doc = $(this).contents();
    doc.find('#yourLink').click(...);
}).appendTo('body');
```

Reference: [`.contents`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/)

Not sure how Chrome handles this for extensions, but it could be that you will have a [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you can control panel.html, just put the js that handles click event in panel.html.