# In Chrome extension, content scripts can't affect inside the iframe?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In the manifest.json file, I declare that I want to inject some scripts, like this:

```
{
    "name": "my extension",

    "version": "1.0",

    "background_page": "background.html",

    "permissions": ["contextMenus", "tabs", "http://*.example.com/*"],

    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches":
                [
                "http://*.taobao.com/*",
                "http://*.yintai.com/*"
                ],
            "run_at": "document_idle",
            "js": ["jquery-1.5.1.min.js","jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js", "contentscript.js"],
            "all_frames": true
        }
    ]
}
```

In the content script, I create an iframe, among other things. It works fine so far. Like this:

```
$('<div id="my_notifier"></div>').appendTo($('body')).html('<iframe src="http://example.com"></iframe>');
```

The problem is, inside the iframe, it does not inherit anything from the content scripts. If I want to use jQuery, I have to use `<script src=...` to include it again inside the iframe.

I prefer not to include jQuery again because I already put it in the extension. I don't want the user to download jQuery again and again on every page that the extension needs to run on.

I've tried the attribute `"all_frames": true`, but it doesn't work.

Please advise. Thanks.

Edit: I added example.com to the `matches` attribute like this:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches":
            [
            "http://*.taobao.com/*",
            "http://*.yintai.com/*", 
            "http://*.example.com/*"
            ],
        "run_at": "document_idle",
        "js": ["jquery-1.5.1.min.js","jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js", "contentscript.js"],
        "all_frames": true
    }
]
```

But it does not work.

To be clearer, say the contents of the iframe (example.com) is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled</title>
</head>

<body>

<div></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('div').html('hi');  

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

There will be an error: $ is not defined

To make it work, I have to use:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled</title>
</head>

<body>

<div></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('div').html('hi');  

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show your full manifest with `all_frames` set and your content script code that creates iframe?

Comment: Hey Betty, now that Serg has solved the initial problem take a look at this question on waiting till the frame has loaded to access it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669089/how-to-inject-an-iframe-panel-to-a-google-chrome-extension-and-add-click-event-in

Comment: Hi Darin, I'm not an expert. I've tried my best to answer the question you mentioned. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add your iframe's url `http://example.com` to the list and specify which content scripts to inject:

```
 "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches":
                [
                "http://*.taobao.com/*",
                "http://*.yintai.com/*"
                ],
            "run_at": "document_idle",
            "js": ["jquery-1.5.1.min.js","jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js", "contentscript.js"]
        },{
            "matches":["http://example.com/*"],
            "run_at": "document_idle",
            "js": ["jquery-1.5.1.min.js"],
            "all_frames": true
        }
    ]
```

Comment: I've tried your way, and another way by simply adding example.com to the `matches` attribute, but with no luck. See the edited question.

PS: I pressed enter to get a new line, and I was surprised to find that the comment was sent. ><

Comment: @Betty It wouldn't work the way you want. Content scripts are sandboxed, a regular page cannot access jquery injected as a content script in it. If example.com frame is part of your extension and you have full control over it, you can move all javascript from that page into a content script and inject it along with jquery.

Comment: Thank you @serg. The content of my example.com frame is dynamically generated, so I can't put it in the extension. I think that means what I want can't be done. I'll have to use <script src=... to include jQuery inside the iframe.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is quiet easy:

- Check if new tab was updated
- Is your Url ?
- Execute the script you want

[dynamically deploying content scripts in chrome extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945541/dynamically-deploying-content-scripts-in-chrome-extensions)