# Accessing iframe from chrome extension

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a chrome extension and bumped into a big problem.

I'm using content scripts to inject my javascript code on a web site. The web site has an iframe.
I can change the source code of the iframe but don't seem to get any access to the iframe's contentWindow property. I need it to insert text at the current carret position.

So basically this code works perfectly in the context of the page:

```
$("#iframe1").contentWindow.document.execCommand("InsertHTML", false, 'test text');
```

But when I try it to run in the context of my chrome extension I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined
```

What's strange is that I can access the html of the iframe. So this code works perfectly from the chrome extension:

```
$("#iframe1").contents().find('div').html('test')
```

I tried putting "all_frames": true in the manifest file but no luck :(

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6645359/502149. You should manipulate the contents of the iframe from a content script injected into the iframe, not from the containing page.

Comment: any luck on this? i'm new to chrome extensions and web dev in general and i'm stuck on the same problem on a pet project.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To understand why your code does not work, I include [a fragment of my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11812786/window-open-returns-undefined-in-chrome-extension/11815581#11815581):

> Content scripts do not have any access to a page's global `window` object. For content scripts, the following applies:
>
> - The **`window`** variable does not refer to the page's global object. Instead, it refers to a new context, a "layer" over the page. The page's DOM is fully accessible. <sup>[#execution-environment](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html#execution-environment)</sup>
>
> Given a document consisting of   `<iframe id="frameName" src="http://domain/"></iframe>`:
>
> - Access to the contents of a frame is restricted by the [Same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) of the page; the permissions of your extension does not relax the policy.
> - `frames[0]` and `frames['frameName']`, (normally referring to the the frame's containing global `window` object) is **`undefined`**.
> - `var iframe = document.getElementById('frameName');`
>
>   - **`iframe.contentDocument`** returns a **`document`** object of the containing frame, because content scripts have access to the DOM of a page. This property is **`null`** when the Same origin policy applies.
>   - **`iframe.contentDocument.defaultView`** (refers to the `window` object associated with the document) is **undefined**.
>   - **`iframe.contentWindow`**  is **undefined**.

#### Solution for same-origin frames

In your case, either of the following will work:

```
// jQuery:
$("#iframe1").contents()[0].execCommand( ... );

// VanillaJS
document.getElementById("iframe1").contentDocument.execCommand( ... );

// "Unlock" contentWindow property by injecting code in context of page
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.textContent = 'document.getElementById("iframe1").contentWindow.document.execCommand( ... );';
document.head.appendChild(s);
```

### Generic solution

The generic solution is using `"all_frames": true` in the manifest file, and use something like this:

```
if (window != top) {
    parent.postMessage({fromExtension:true}, '*');
    addEventListener('message', function(event) {
        if (event.data && event.data.inserHTML) {
            document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, event.data.insertHTML);
        }
    });
} else {
    var test_html = 'test string';
    // Explanation of injection at https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879/938089 :
    // Run code in the context of the page, so that the `contentWindow`
    //  property becomes accessible
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.textContent = '(' + function(s_html) {
        addEventListener('message', function(event) {
            if (event.data.fromExtension === true) {
                var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe1');
                if (iframe && (iframe.contentWindow === event.source)) {
                    // Window recognised, post message back
                    iframe.contentWindow.postMessage({insertHTML: s_html}, '*');
                }
            }
        });
    } + ')(' + JSON.stringify(test_html) + ');';
    (document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
    script.parentNode.removeChild(script);
}
```

This demo is for educational purposes only, **do not use this demo in a real extension**. Why? Because it uses [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage) to pass messages around. These events can also be generated by the client, which causes a security leak (XSS: arbitrary HTML injection).

The alternative to `postMessage` is Chrome's message API. For a demo, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11325415/access-iframe-content-from-a-chromes-extension-content-script/11326942#11326942). You won't be able to compare the `window` objects though. What you *can* do is to rely the `window.name` property. The `window.name` property is automatically set to the value of the iframe's `name` attribute (just once, when the iframe is loaded).

Comment: @Rob W I tried doing same but chrome is showing 'same-origin-policy' error now. I guess they have updated their flags. `Blocked a parent from accessing cross-origin-frame (child frame)`

Comment: it doesn't work anymore with Manifest 3. Mb some permissions are needed?