# Chrome extension: Set action when user clicks in iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I've got a browser extension that shows a menu, which is loaded in an iframe. I've chosen this setup, so I can update the menu without having to update the browser extension. Some actions from the menu result in a change in the page. The (crucial) issue I am having though, is that I so far haven't succeeded to detect when the user clicks on a button in the iframe.

From my understanding, best would be to have a listener from content.js, but happy to use any other approach if it works :)

The function in content.js that loads the menu, including a not functioning listener:

```
function showMenu() {
  // Avoid recursive frame insertion...
  var extensionOrigin = 'chrome-extension://' + chrome.runtime.id;
  if (!location.ancestorOrigins.contains(extensionOrigin)) {
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    // Must be declared at web_accessible_resources in manifest.json
    iframe.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('menu.html');

    // Some styles for a fancy sidebar
    iframe.style.cssText = "\
                            position:fixed;\
                            bottom:33%;\
                            right:0px;\
                            width:47px;\
                            height:198px;\
                            margin:0;\
                            padding:0;\
                            border:none;\
                            overflow:hidden;\
                            background:transparent;\
                            z-index:999999;\
                        ";
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    menuListener(iframe);
  }
}

function menuListener()
  {
    jQuery(document).on("click", '#click-me', function() {
        alert('Works!');
    });
  }
```

menu.html which is part of the extension and is a web_accessable_resource:

```
<style>
html, body, iframe, h2 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border:none;
    display: block;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: transparent;
    color: black;
}
h2 {
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
iframe {
    height: calc(100vh - 50px);
}
</style>

<iframe id="rpm-menu" src="https://www.example.com/"></iframe>
```

And then the div on the external page which is to be clicked:

```
  <div id="click-me" class="menu-icon">
    <p>CLICK</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hey @Vincent, I think this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266192/accessing-iframe-from-chrome-extension?rq=1 if i got you question correctly.

Comment: Looks pretty spot on, thanks. I will work through and post feedback here later this week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the Message API will be the best way to solve this, since there is more information I will need to pass in both directions.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging